# jQuery checking localStorage and if empty / null to refresh an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have everything working on my cart so far, but when I click delete on the mini cart I can't seem to get it to check the localStorage and if empty array to reset a few elements. If I refresh the page it does change the cart count to 0 and the price to 0.00 but not updating when I click delete. I have to refresh and struggling.

Delete action:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page 

    var item = $(this).data('item'); // get data item to delete
    deleteItem(item);
    $(".basket").hide();
});
```

Functions:

```
function deleteItem(index){
  if (localStorage.basket) {
    basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.basket);
    basket.splice(index,1); // delete item at index
    saveBasket();
    updateBasket();
  }

  return;
}
```

save function:

```
// Save the basket
function saveBasket(){
    if (window.localStorage){
        localStorage.basket = JSON.stringify(basket);
    }
}
```

update function:

```
function updateBasket(){
  $.each(basket, function(product) {
    //console.log(basket);
    // update the basket count
    //basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.basket);

    //if(basket[product].qty === "0" || basket === null || basket.length === 0){
    if(basket[product].qty === "0"){
      $('.mini-cart .count').html("0");
    } else {
      $('.mini-cart .count').html(basket[product].qty); // set the cart amount
    }

    // update the basket total
    if(basket[product].price > 0){
      var finalPrice = basket[product].price * basket[product].qty; // calculate the price and how many
      $('.mini-cart .price').html("&pound;"+finalPrice);
    } else {
      $('.mini-cart .price').html("Basket is empty");
    }
  });

  return;
}
```

Comment: Like i said, it is removing the item as expected but wanting it to update the count and price elements. thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if basket has length. If it does you enter the `each` loop, otherwise you would do whatever reset is needed.

```
function updateBasket(){
  if(!window.basket || !basket.length){
    // do reset
  }else{    
      $.each(basket, function(product) {...
  }
}
```

Comment: Did give that a try, replacing my condition within the each but did not work out should i do outside of the each? thanks for the your help btw!

Comment: If there is no basket or no length `each` won't run. Did you try it the way I wrote it?

Comment: Oh sorry, 4am been at this all day as prototype demo in morning.... give me 5 mins :)

Comment: Yep works a treat mate!! had to get it all together but working great!! life saver! thanks a lot for your help mate! Top dude!